# How to stop a cat from being aggressive towards me and others?

Tags: cats, training, aggression

How do i stop my cat from being aggressive towards me and others? I just bought my cat three-days ago and had no problem but this morning I woke up to check on my cat but when I tried to touch her she has been very aggressive. She tries to bite my hand aggressively and now I cant even touch my own cat.

I got her from overstock.com because I seen that they were now selling animals online. I am going to get her to the vet tomorrow to see what the veterinarian says. I also noticed that she has not eaten her food nor drank her water. She also seems to not use the bathroom so I tried to look around and see what she gotten into and so far there was nothing she had gotten into. Is there any way I can check to see if she is alright without her trying to hurt me?

Comment: Overstock does not sell animals, they have a platform to put people in touch with local rescues/shelters. Do you need to edit your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need to provide attention towards a cat until gets a habit littering, food and drink. It may take up to a week at most. As it is new to you it may take 4 or 5 days to become familiarized with you and your family. How old is your cat? It would be an easy task if it's ages is below 2 months. Kittens usually try to bite or scratch you, the way they behave with siblings or mother. But soon they learn not to use nails and not to bite.

Comment: Well I just got my cat three-days ago. I guess she is three days old?

Comment: No its not three days old. A 3 day old cat can't open her eyes. I think it might be 15-20 days old, which is very young. You need to care a lot. Generally mothers train them to litter at a particular place. If it is doesn't, then you'll need to keep at it there frequently. She is too small to realize you are not a cat. But soon she won't scratch you when she realizes it hurts you.

Comment: I bought my cat from overstock and she has no mother currently. She is just alone with nothing but me. Also I do care for my cat but I understand what you trying to say.